# how to handle write to file system, use local folders etc in azure web apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, provider-hosted-app, web-application, azure

i am migrating provider hosted app to SharePoint online by deploying it to Azure Web apps. How to handle write to file system and local folder access as we will not have file system in azure web apps?

Also what are all the changes required in web.config file of Prover hosted app while migrating it to SharePoint Online?

Comment: do you want to write Error log in File system or you have any other work like creating a file or updating a file using Provider hosted apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **have** file system in Azure Web app and you can write to it. <s>The only important thing is, that you **can't** rely on a file system as a permanent storage for your files.</s>   As per comments, `D:\home` is [persisted](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system). You can write to this directory and data should be persisted across all instances and never deleted.

Additionally, for permanent file storage solution you can use other things provided by Azure:
[Azure blob storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/)

Comment: can you please check my 2nd query as well? what are all the changes required in web.config file of Provider hosted app while migrating it to SharePoint Online? Only we need to change client id and client secret or some other changes are also required?

Comment: Only ClientId and Client secret, apart from that nothing else. In the end Azure Web app is just a VM with IIS, that's why everything should work.

Comment: Anything in D:\home\ is persisted across restarts (otherwise your app will get deleted too).  D:\local (?) is temporary.  App Services are also running 24/7.  You’re paying for a dedicated VM whether you’re running 0, 1 or 50 sites.  There is no VM spin down.  The app pool on the other hand may spin down (unless you’ve configured always on).

Comment: @AdarshAwasthi please take a note on a comment - everything in D:\home is persisted. I was not aware of such things.

Comment: @GregW thank for pointing that out. I should correct my answer, beause I used outdated information.

Comment: @GregW it will be cool if you provide your own answer, because it's more valid I think

Comment: TBH there’s tons of quality documentation already out there on docs.microsoft.com on how the Azure App Service works.  I’d just be copy/pasting.  Where I work, we haven’t quite got to the stage of integrating Azure Web Apps with SPO but it’s on our radar.

Comment: @GregW Could you provide those links? Will be very useful for everybody.

Comment: Links are discouraged as they can change, breaking the discussion for future searches.  There’s tons of getting started guides available, just search for them.

Comment: I meant where did you read about 24/7 and dedicated VM which never goes shut down, etc. Do you have the link? I haven't found anything. I'm asking because I read another information, that there might be cases when your site is moved between VMs, you might lose some files you wrote in the file system. That's why the recommended way is to use external storage for files. Now I see that the situation is different.

Comment: Sorry.  Just saw the notification.  Operating System Functionality in Azure App Service - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-available-operating-system-functionality and Azure Web App Sandbox - https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox